# python library 'json' prints everything twice

Tags: python, json

I decided to make a very simple program to get started with json in Python 3.4.3

However, it seemed I only write two lines before I encountered something weird; it prints everything twice. The program is just this:

```
import json

jsonFile = open('TODO.json','r').read()
print(jsonFile)
```

This prints the string twice. If I remove the 'import json' it works just fine. Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm pretty sure you called your script `json.py` which shadows the builtin json module. Then your script imports itself and the code is run twice.

Comment: Looks like @Matthias is right. When a module is imported, everything in it gets executed. Also, try putting your code from jsonFile an on inside the if-statement if \_\_name\_\_ == '\_\_main\_\_': That will tell Python not to execute it on import but only when the module is executed explicitly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Okay, so I named py file json.py. Did not think that through

Comment: This is the correct answer because I just did the same.

Comment: I feel like the small, most stupid mistakes like this takes up the most time

Comment: Lol this answer is a godsend. Figured it out in 2 minutes instead of probably like an hour.